# Math operations with static and non static variables

Tags: java, static

Can I multiply a static and a non static variables, like this:

```
public class C {  
    protected int c;  
    private static int s;  
    public int ma() { return this.c*this.s; }  
}
```

Or:

```
public class B{  
    protected int x;  
    private static int y;  
    public static int ms() { return x + y; }  
}
```

The second code is not working and I am wondering is it because it's expecting static?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The second block of code is not working because `ms` is `static`. You cannot reference non-`static` members (`x`) from a `static` context.

You need to either make `ms` a non-`static` function or make `x` a `static` variable.

Like this:

```
public class B{  
    protected static int x;  // now static
    private static int y;  
    public static int ms() { return x + y; }  
}
```

Or like this:

```
public class B{  
    protected int x;  
    private static int y;  
    public int ms() { return x + y; }  // now non-static
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A static variable/function is one that is shared across the application.  In your second example

```
public class B{  
    protected int x;  
    private static int y;  
    public static int ms() { return x + y; }  
}
```

Your method is declared static and is therefore a static context.  Rule of thumb: You can't access non-static things from a static context.  Here is some reasoning as to why that is.

Say you have two objects of type `B` one where `x=1` and one where `x=2`.  Since `y` is static it is shared by both objects.  Let `y=0`.

Suppose from somewhere else in your program you call `B.ms()`. You're not referring to any particular `B` object.  Therefore the JVM is unable to add `x + y` because it doesn't know what value of `x` to use.  Make sense?